# dir /X - 8:3 path name is not working on one drive

Tags: windows

I was cleaning up some stuff on my C drive using SpaceSniffer, and now on my D drive, paths with spaces in them are no longer showing the short 8:3 form when using dir /X.  To test things, I've created the exact same folder name on the C and D drive, and only the D drive is having this issue.  Now things like my builds are broken when running on that drive.  So, what could possibly do this to my drive?  It's NTFS ... it had the option to index the contents, in addition to file properties (trying to remove that now), but other than that, it looks the same as the C drive.

Comment: You *want* 8.3 file names? What is the value of HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation?

Comment: Yes, because some build scripts don't know how to handle spaces in path names, 8:3 support is required.  It was working earlier today.  So something changed ... NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation is set to 2.  How can that be for one drive and not the other? :S

Comment: @RyanRies So, I guess SpaceSniffer must have changed that registry key.  I put it back to the default of 0, and now creating a test dir, works again.  However, all the files/folders I have pulled down from source control have to be recreated.  Thanks, put your comment as an answer and you get the points. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation
```

should be set to 2, which stands for "allow 8.3 file name creation to be configured on a per-volume basis."  Yours was set to 2, which is good.

```
fsutil 8dot3name set D: 0
```

That will enable short name creation on the D drive.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like SpaceSniffer just jacked with your config and you just needed to set it back.

Comment: i tried to execute the same command as yours, but the difference is. I use : fsutil 8dot3name set D:\myFolder 0 .... but the result is Access Denied? any clue ? it's my file. I am using administrator user here. :( @Ryan help.

Comment: @gumuruh 8.3 name creation is not controlled on a per-file or per-directory basis. It is on a per-volume basis. It is not set on a directory. It's for the whole volume. Therefore, the command that you just specified is invalid.

Comment: okay, now i tried to set the drive only without entering the directory path. But once i reopened the DOS window, the naming still in full mode, instead of short mode... what should I do then? @Ryan...

Comment: @gumuruh Maybe you have a Group Policy that is overriding your settings. I advise you to please open up a new question and include the exact command you're using and the exact output from fsutil.